# Inquiring sites for mathematics video lectures

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I need some site names that provide research oriented mathematics video lectures for free. I came across some but even on my broad band connection they do not play videos smoothly. If anyone can tell me sites like you tube that plays videos very smoothly then it will be a great accomplishment.

Comment: The MIT open courseware videos run off of YouTube so they may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have seen some of them but they are merely for general audience.

Comment: Catsters on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/user/thecatsters ?

Comment: Have a look at the [MSRI website](http://www.msri.org/web/msri/home): they often have seminars and workshops available on video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is something more to do with your connection than anything.

I would recommend looking at the universities listed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCourseWare (there are many and maybe some have the sort of materials and quality you are looking for).

There are potentially others things such as: http://archive.org/details/msri

Maybe if we had a better idea of which topics you have interest in, we could provide more guidance.

Enjoy! -A

Comment: My concern is more focused in geometry and linear algebra.

Comment: Just click on G in the site mentioned (http://archive.org/details/msri) for many lectures on Geometry. For LA, I would look to the OpenCourseWare schools as there are many wonderful lectures/courses in these areas and maybe one of the schools is better than other for the video quality you seek. Enjoy! -A

Comment: Certainly a great help.Thanks a lot @Amzoti.

Comment: @  Abhinav you are welcome. I also wanted to note that the big name international universities in other countries have also started using OpenCourseWare, see, for exampl, Oxford's site. Hope you find what you seek!

Comment: Great link to start the OP off with!

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of video links here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1714/best-online-mathematics-videos

and here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free

Comment: Thanks.I will follow these links.